# Bash - does the awk function have a built in julian day function?

Tags: awk

I have a csv file where the 1st column is the date and time the data was generated - I am trying to use awk to convert that date into a julian day and add it as an extra column on the end

"2021-01-22 22:02:00",475673,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.308788,-4.421722,-99
"2021-01-22 23:03:00",475674,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.329033,-4.373959,-99
"2021-01-22 24:04:00",475675,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.320374,-4.359528,-99
"2021-01-22 25:05:00",475676,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.329685,-4.494766,-99
"2021-01-22 26:06:00",475677,485,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.343422,-4.650154,-99

I have written a script in bash that is called when a file arrives for processing. I have tried a couple of different variation on the below

`awk '{ jday=date -d(substr($0,2,10)) +%j;print $0","jday }' temp.CMP`

The reason I am using the awk command is because I am also extracting the year, month, day, hour, minute data and adding as individual columns on the end of each line.

is what I am trying possible using awk in Bash?

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you mean seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 UTC)

Comment: GNU awk has time functions, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions. The script you posted is an awk script, not a bash (or any other shell) script so you should try to directly call other Unix tools like `date` from within it. awk and bash are 2 completely different tools, each with their own syntax, semantics, scope, functions, etc. You can all other Unix tools indirectly from awk in a couple of different ways (just like you can from C) but not the way you are trying to do it - there are plenty of examples in the archives of this forum.

Comment: `awk` is not a function. It is a programming language and utility. You don't even need the `bash` to use `awk`.

Comment: sorry for the my misunderstanding there folks thanks for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to GNU awk, you can try the following:

```
awk -F, '{ dattim=gensub("[-:\"]"," ","g",$1);print $0","strftime("%j",mktime(dattim))}' file
```

Use gensub to replace all "-" and ":" entries for a space in the first comma delimited field. Read the result into the variable dattim. Then use this variable along with strftime and mktime functions to append the julian format date to the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks Raman, I've tried this but I'm getting an error from strftime because the date being produced by the mktime functionv = -1, I undersatnd the concept, so i'll play around with this and let you know when I figure it out. thanks again

Comment: It works fine with the example line in a file. Can you make sure that the example is in exactly in the same format as the example and that the fields are comma separated.

Comment: Solution was tested with GNU Awk 4.0.2

Comment: I can confirm the same version of GNU Awk - I have updated the data sample - Sorry for the confusion I have being working on this data for a few days and confused myself.

Comment: OK, I amended the answer to remove the double quotes from the date/time first field. Give it a go.